# JTable date column sort freezes

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am working with a JTable that contains a few columns with different datatypes (int, string, date). When I run the app the data displays fine but if I use the column headers to sort the data it freezes on the columns that contain Date objects. Below is the code. Columns 8, 9, & 10 are the ones causing the problem. How do I make it so the Date columns are sortable?

```
public void updateLogTable() {

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) logTable.getModel();
    List<LogObject> lstLogObjects = new ArrayList<LogObject>();
    lstLogObjects = LogManager.getLog();
    for (int i = 0; i < lstLogObjects.size(); i++) {
        Object[] temp = new Object[13];

        temp[0] = Integer.parseInt(lstLogObjects .get(i).getLogID());
        temp[1] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getLogType();
        temp[2] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getYear();
        temp[3] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getQuarter();
        temp[4] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getOriginalID();
        temp[5] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getSubject();
        temp[6] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getAction();
        temp[7] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getRequester();
        temp[8] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getADate(); //Returns java.util.Date
        temp[9] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getCDate(); //Returns java.util.Date
        temp[10] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getSDate(); //Returns java.util.Date
        temp[11] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getRemarks();
        temp[12] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getField1();

        model.addRow(temp);

    }
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
 }
```

Comment: What type does `getADate()` return?

Comment: Sorry. I updated the code with comments. It returned java.util.Date

Comment: @Woodszy what returns System.out.println(lstLogObjects .get(i).getADate()); something like as Fri Jan 10 00:00:00 GTM 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you override the getColumnClass(...) method of your TableModel to return the proper class?

The table sort methods will then sort the column and treat it as a Date rather than invoke toString() on the Date object.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was using Netbeans generated code for defining the JTable so it made it a bit more difficult to customize the table. But your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using JXTable for anything less trivial than displaying two columns. Basic intro is for example [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91834162.html).

Other option is to use Long as element in table and use column renderer which would format date:

```
 temp[8] = lstLogObjects .get(i).getADate().getTime()

 table.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setCellRenderer( new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                                        int row, int column){
        Object value2 = value; 
        if(row>0 && column==8) //put your own condition here
             value2 = new Date((Long)value).toString(); //your own formatting here
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value2,
                                          isSelected, hasFocus,
                                          row, column);
     }
  });
 }
```

Comment: Not very efficient to continually convert a Long variable to a Date every time you want to render a cell.